# 20k products - 500 attributes

Tags: magento2

So we're trying to launch a webshop with over 20k products and 500 attributes (and counting). We purchased the Wyomind mass importer module but it seems this module is not capable of handling that many SKU's and attributes.

Is there any module someone can recommend for this many SKU's and attributes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

store manager for magento will handle thousands of entities, you can download the trial for testing

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest that separate the attributes to multiple files, such as

file 1: sku, website_id, attribute 1 -> 100

file 2: sku, website_id, attribute 101 -> 200

file 3: sku, website_id, attribute 201 -> 300
...

You must ensure that all required attributes are merged into a single file before creating products.